# Get Avg value in Doctrine / symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i try to get AVG value in doctrine, in my Repositoru i do this:

```
public function getFotoSpecifica($idFoto) {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
    $q->leftJoin("f.foto_votata", 'v');
    $q->where('f.id =:idFoto');
    $q->andWhere('(f.foto_privata IS NULL OR f.foto_privata != 1)');
    $q->andWhere('(f.foto_eliminata IS NULL OR f.foto_eliminata != 1)');
    $q->expr()->avg('v.punteggio',  true);
    $q->setParameter('idFoto', $idFoto);
    $dql = $q->getQuery();
    $results = $dql->getArrayResult();
    return $results;
}
```

but i don't find any value avg, i see all my object...i try to use createQuery in my controller but i have many errors like: Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression. ( this is a foreign key)

mySql query is:

```
SELECT profilo_id, proprietario_id, round(AVG( punteggio ),2) as avg_rate, SUM(punteggio) as score, foto_id, count(*) as numero_votanti

 FROM prof_voto_foto
 WHERE foto_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable  name for the foreign key is named $foto and the entity is ProfVotoFoto
In your controller you can do something like this.

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $q=$em->createQuery("
          SELECT profilo_id, proprietario_id, round(AVG( punteggio ),2) as avg_rate,
          SUM(punteggio) as score, foto_id, count(*) as numero_votanti
          FROM YourBundleName:ProfVotoFoto f
          WHERE f.foto = :idFoto
   ")
     ->setPArameter('idFoto',$idFoto);

    $averageResult = $q->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: i try with 

$query = $em->createQuery('
SELECT v.id, v.profilo
          FROM SNFotoBundle:Voti v
          WHERE v.foto= :idFoto

      ')
            ->setParameter('idFoto', intval($id_immagine) );

profilo is ManyToOne / @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profilo_id", referencedColumnName="id")

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to add a select statement to query. Also possible requires to add `group by`.

```
->addSelect('AVG(v.punteggio) as punteggio_avg')
```

Comment: i try with ->addSelect('AVG(v.punteggio) as punteggio_avg'), and $q->groupBy('v.foto'); but i don't find my punteggio_avg in var dump